# Will creating a new account overwrite save games on linked phones?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have linked up with my brother's phone with same ID but I want to start a new account of CoC on my phone. I don't know if my brother's game will be deleted or not. Please help me out!

In short: me and my brother's email ID is the same, so we play with the same account on CoC but I want to start a new account on my own phone.

Answer (score 0):

In Clash of Clans, only one save can be saved to each account (not sure what OS you are using). Your best bet is to use a separate account to play COC.